# Three.js Render Artifacts

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am having odd rending artifacts when I am working with collada models loaded using three.js. I cannot find a solution within the limited documentation of the API and I have tried a few different property changes to no avail. I have tried to change the shading and side settings of the material and some other properties of the geometry and material of the object.

Current Code (Irrelevant parts removed):

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  specular: '#ffffff',
  color: 0xaaaaaa,
  shininess: 5
});
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load("objectPath", function (collada) {
  var dae = collada.scene.getDescendants()[0]; // 
  var geometry = dae.geometry;
  geometry.mergeVertices();
  geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  dae.scale.x = dae.scale.y = dae.scale.z = APP.getVar('SCALE');
  dae.updateMatrix(loader.options.convertUpAxis = true);
  dae.material = material;
  APP.getScene().add(dae);  
});
```

Pictures of problem:

[image: Visual Representation of Problem (1)]
[image: Visual Representation of Problem (2)]
[image: Visual Representation of Problem (3)]

Comment: If someone can at least tell me what this kind of artifact is known as, it would help.

Comment: for some faces the vertices are defined clockwise and for others counter-clockwise. They should all be counter-clockwise.

Comment: Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: from the modelling software

Comment: I checked the models and all of the vertices are oriented correctly (I checked the normals using Blender).

Comment: if you remove the `geometry.mergeVertices();` do you still see the problem?

Comment: Yes, the problem existed before the merging was added. These pictures may actually be from before the merging was added (although that was the only change).